# Android device not shown with adb

Tags: android, linux, adb

I have searched for a long time for this, I have tried all the tricks I could find...

I have been debugging on the same device *for a few months*, deploying the app on other exact same devices flawlessly. But since *last week*, I can no longer connect to it. Connecting the device via USB, I can hear the computer's sound warn about the connected device, and I can see in Chrome that it is recognized

[image]

However, adb won't detect it.

[image]

Unfortunately, I have not access to root on the devices, so I'm not sure how to connect via TCP/IP.

What could possibly be the problem?

**Note:** I am working with Ubuntu.

**Note 2:** The devices run Android 4.4.2, as reported by the device, despite specs from various vendors say otherwise.

---

### Update

I have verified my UDEV rules, so

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 123: ID 1f3a:1002 Onda (unverified) 
...
```

is the only device added when I connect the tablet via USB. And in my `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules` file (which I have already set over a year ago), I have the correct line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f3a", MODE="0666"
```

The **Developer Options** are

- Take bug report
- Desktop backup password
- Stay awake
- HDCP checking
- Process Stats

#### Debugging

- USB debugging  *(= ON)*
- Power menu bug reports
- Allow mock locations  *(= ON)*
- Select debug app
- *(disabled)* Wait for debugger
- Verify apps over USB
- Wireless display certification

#### Input

- Show touches
- Pointer location

#### Drawing

- Show surface updates
- Show layout bounds
- Force RTL layout direction
- Window animation scale
- Transition animation scale
- Animator duraction scale
- Simluate secondary displays

#### Hardware acceleration rendering

- Force GPU rendering
- Show GPU new updates
- Show hardware layers updates
- Debug GPU overdraw
- Debug non-rectangular clip operations
- Force 4x MSAA
- Disable HW overlays

#### Monitoring

- Strict mode enabled
- Show CPU usage
- Profile GPU rendering
- Enable GPU traces

#### Apps

- Don't keep activites  *(= ON)*
- Background process limit  *(= standard)*
- Show all ANRs

(All options with values or set are indicated in the above list. If nothing is mentioned, then no value is set.)

Comment: Try revoking the rights for all devices from the phone and reconnect it again.

Comment: Have you set your device for debugging?
Also, be aware that your device asks you for fingerprint acknowledge. If you do not grant this permission, adb wont work.

Comment: @PrerakSola how do I do that?

Comment: @TiagoDávila of course the device is on debug mode; I did deploy on this exact device many times already. And I'm not sure what you mean by "fingerprint"; the device never asked me anything, and just worked.

Comment: Settings -> Developer options -> Revoke USB debugging authorizations

Comment: @PrerakSola there is no such option on the device.

Comment: It should be there below `USB Debugging`. What's your OS version?

Comment: @YanickRochon, go to Settings and go to about device and under Software information, click on Build number repeatedly until you are notified that "You are now a developer". USB Debugging should then appear under the Settings menu. What kind of phone are you using?

Comment: @PrerakSola Android 4.4.2. ... I was searching for the specs online for the model (776TPCII) but everywhere it says 4.2, while the device truly reports 4.4.2.

Comment: @ic90 as I said, the device is already on debug mode. And the question was updated to show `Android 4.4.2`.

Comment: What are the setting options under `Developer options`? Can you add the list to your question?

Comment: Try updating your udev rules: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/UDEV

Comment: @PrerakSola question udpated

Comment: @YanickRochon Just to confirm that you didn't have Chrome remote debugging on when trying stuff with adb. Also what is your 'adb version'.

Comment: @MorrisonChang put that into an answer, you got the winning shot. Holy crap! I would've not guessed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've got Chrome Remote debugging working, just make sure that Chrome debugging isn't running when doing things with adb on the command line.

I believe that Chrome has its own version of adb-server so that would conflict with the one used by Android Studio.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Developer Mode first in the Mobile and then connect the device to your linux machine. It require no drivers, happy debugging.

Comment: Please, read the question carefully. I said that I have used this same device for debugging before... several times... then it stopped being listed last week. I then replied to comments by listing all the Developer Mode menu... entirely!

Answer (score 0):

> yalok commented on 17 Apr @ gituhub threat https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/130

Managed to run the session-manager after:

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/anbox /usr/bin/anbox
```

adb device is now there:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-6663   device
```