# Chrome Remote Debugging - "Pending Authentication"

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I connect my HTC10 to my Windows 7 PC and initially Chrome gives me this message. If I manually start the adb server with `adb start-server` it connects to the device, but as soon as I try to inspect a page on the device I get disconnected without any error and it returns to "Pending Authentication"

I have tried reinstalling everything involved, restarting devices, revoking USB authorizations, disabling and re-enabling USB debugging... I have no idea what else to try. There is no prompt to "Accept Debugging" on my device.

Has anyone solved this before? Thanks very much

[image]

Comment: When trying Chrome Remote Debugging, don't have adb-server running, and vice-versa: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40723376/295004 (don't have Remote Debugging on when doing adb stuff)

Comment: Like I mentioned, it gives me that message unless I turn adb-server on, and if I do turn it on, it goes away, but only for ~30 seconds.

Comment: You might want to list out versions for Chrome and Android SDK tools (especially adb). Other than checking if the tools are up to date, all I can think of is to check on a different PC to see if its something local to you current PC.

Answer (score 8):

I can't solve this for good, but I do work around it.

If I click the "USB Debugging Connected" notification to go to the developer settings, revoke previous authorizations, and turn off then on USB debugging, I can force the authorization popup again. Annoying, though.

Answer (score 8):

Try to change your USB Cable. I had the same problem and I did that now it works. Sometimes the bad quality of the cable can cause such errors.

Comment: It's incredible, but it was the cable... When they say you, "Try everything", you actually need to try it all.

Comment: It's incredible, but it was the cable... When they say you, "Try everything", you actually need to try it all.

Comment: The reason for this is that not all micro-USB cables have data transfer capability. Some are only good for charging.

Answer (score 4):

After trying a different cable, and disabling and re-enabling USB debugging and Developer mode, I found that I had to switch the USB Preferences to File Transfer, and then I finally got the authentication dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I went into Developer Options on the device, disabled "USB Debugging" and enabled it again.. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling background processes.

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling everything in Debugging (except USB debugging) + setting background processes to 4 did work for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, rebooting the Android device worked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'd mentioned that rebooting didn't resolve it in this case.