# Do I need ADB for Chrome remote debugging?

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb

I often use Chrome remote debugging from my PC to my Android phone. I always thought that ADB needs to be started and authorized for this to work.

Now I'm on a machine where I don't have Android Studio installed and I'm checking the [Chrome DevTools Remote Debugging page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to see if I absolutely have to install it or if maybe there is a standalone package just for Chrome remote debugging. Guess what, ADB isn't even mentioned! The page makes it look like I don't need to install anything (besides Chrome and the phone's drivers) for remote debugging to work.

Currently I can't get it to work, my phone isn't recognized by Chrome. Would installing ADB (by installing Android Studio or an Android SDK) likely fix that?

Comment: What phone (make/model/OS version) do you have? From what I recall, [Chrome has its own adb server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728390/295004) Also double check that the USB cable can transmit data.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Galaxy Note 3, Android 4.4.2. The USB connection works, I can access the phone's files. On the machine with Android Studio remote debugging works with that phone. That's a helpful hint about Chrome having a builtin ADB.